# defining view size in centimeters in android

Tags: android, view, size

I want to make an edit box of 1cm*1cm in size.
It should be of 1cm*1cm size on all the resolutions and on all the screens.
Is their any way in android so that i can define height or width in cms ?
It will be of great help , if someone can provide me solution for it.

Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [More Resource Types # Dimension](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension)

There is a unit called `mm` for Millimeters.

> **mm**
>   Millimeters - Based on the physical size of the screen.

So `10mm` are equal to `1cm`.

Source is this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2025541/1482388) on this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025282/difference-of-px-dp-dip-and-sp-in-android)

Comment: Following is  code in my dimensions xml  :                          <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

  <resources>
    <dimen name="centimeter">30mm</dimen>
</resources>                                                              And i used it in this way :-                                        <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/centimeter"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/centimeter"
        android:text="B" 
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>

Comment: i tried it on two emulators of same resolution but of different size. but on smaller screen , size of button was also smaller than that in bigger one . :(

Answer (score 1):

You may use "in" or "mm" as dimensional units for your layouts, that correspond to the inches or millimetres.